# Meaning of "set aside"

Tags: phrase-meaning, literature

> In the Middle Ages, most churches had a cell **set aside** for a person seeking sanctuary. At Notre Dame it was a small room toward the top of the cathedral. It was here that Quasimodo had placed the gypsy girl.

Does this mean: They built sanctuary in a place **apart from main building of church**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell (small room) was already part of the church. The priests decided to use it as a sanctuary. 'Aside' is not always referring to physical location. The phrasal verb 'set aside' means to reserve for a particular use. Each month I set aside some money for my bills. Buses have seats which are set aside for elderly people. A school might set aside a room for quiet study. Note: the past participle of the verb 'set' is also 'set'.

[Set aside something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-aside-something)

Answer (score 0):

I think that:
Set aside here means(kept)It means that there was a room kept for the people seeking refuge

These rooms could be in the main building or outside the main building(depending on the structure of churches in the middle ages)